# jQuery script not working as expected when opening another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

I'm working on implementing Google Analytics in my website, which I'm currently building. I have a link in my page that opens a PDF file and I'm trying to track the number of file opens.

Using the javascript console in Chrome and because the alert box opens, I can determine that the following code works.

```
<a id="ga-link" href="path.to.my.file.com">Open PDF file</a>

<script>
(function( $ ) {
    $("#ga-link").on("click", function( event ){
        event.preventDefault();
        gtag('event', 'view', {
        'filetype':'pdf',
        'filename':'file1',
        'event_callback': function() {alert("1");}
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

But if I replace

`'event_callback': function() {alert("1");}`

with

`'event_callback': function() {$(#ga-link).click();}`

which is what I actually want to do, the script doesn't run. Instead, the file is directly opened (no tracking info sent to Analytics).

I also tried using the javascript code from the [Google Analytics documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/sending-data#implement_event_callback_functions):

```
var btn = document.getElementById('ga-link');
btn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    gtag('event', 'view', {
        'filetype':'pdf',
        'filename':'file1',
        'event_callback': function() {btn.click();}
    });
});
```

This straight up doesn't work at all, no matter what my `'event_callback'` function is.

In both cases, I have tried opening the PDF in the same tab and in a new tab, with the same results.

Comment: It is because the events are becoming circular. btn.click() is calling is back again through the event listener "click".

Comment: Damn. That looks so obvious in retrospect

Comment: How would you solve this though? I'm not familiar enough with js or jquery to see an obvious solution.

Comment: I am totaly sure that my answer covers your problem. I did some syntax mistakes (forgot quotes), so please check my answer again and apply code as it is now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Google example they used `form` as an example. So if you `preventDefault()`on form submit button - it prevents submition, but later you can submit form directly - `form.submit()`. In your case, button always prevents default - even in your callback function.

There are some ways to "cancel" preventDefault. One could be:

```
var btn = document.getElementById('ga-link');

var sendData = function() {
    this.preventDefault();
    gtag('event', 'view', {
        'filetype':'pdf',
        'filename':'file1',
        'event_callback': function() {
           $('#ga-link').unbind('click').click();
           // your code to open url etc.
           btn.addEventListener('click', sendData);
         }
    });
});

btn.addEventListener('click', sendData);
```

Comment: Weird. This doesn't work either. Also, I'd rather not have the link stop functioning as it may need to be opened again. Is there any other workaround to this?

Comment: Can you try `$('#ga-link').unbind('click').click()`. I just realised that `$(this)` refers to gtag properties object..

Comment: If your link opens a new page, you must do this, according to Google. But you can `unbind('click').click()` any time you need

Comment: Oh.. I didn't notice the `$(this)` in your code. `$(#ga-link).unbind('click').click();` was what I tried and it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you added quotes? Its not like `$(#ga-link)` it should be `$('#ga-link')`

Comment: Yeah.. My comment had a syntax error. Its not what I have in my code. Here's what happens with this code. The first time i click the link, the GA data is sent, but nothing else happens. Subsequent clicks open the file without running the script. I've found another solution though. I'll post it in a few mins.

Comment: Yes, I opened my pc to write, that `unbind('click')` unbinds your binded click event for future clicks. SO one way would be to bind same event again. And to get other needed actions - you need to tell that in your callback. I dont know what other actions you need

Comment: I edited my answer. Please comment if that doesnt fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that there was a circular call to the click event as pointed out by TejSoft in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47826083/jquery-script-not-working-as-expected-when-opening-another-page?noredirect=1#comment82615251_47826083).
Here's what I did.

```
(function( $ ) {
    $("#ga-link").on("click", function( event ){
        event.preventDefault();
        gtag('event', 'view', {
            'filetype':'pdf',
            'filename':'file1',
            'event_callback': function() {
                $('#ga-link').unbind('click');           /*to prevent repeat data from being sent to GA*/
                window.open($('#ga-link').attr('href'));/*opens file*/
                }
            });
        }
})(jQuery);
```